# overloading Postfix and prefix operators

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am wondering if this is the correct code for overloading post and pre increment operators.

How can I call these operators in main().

```
class fix{
int x;
int y;
public:fix(int = 0, int = 0);
   fix operator++(){//prefix increment
       fix a;
       ++a.x;
       ++a.y; 
       return a;
}
   fix operator++(int){ //post fix increment
       fix c;
       c.x = x;
       c.y = y;
       x++; y++;
       return c;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This operator

```
   fix operator++(){
       fix a;
       ++a.x;
       ++a.y; 
       return a;
}
```

is not applied to the original object. That is it does not change the original object. Of course you may define it such a way but it will confuse users and have unusual behaviour.

It is better to define it the following way

```
   fix & operator ++()
   {
       ++x;
       ++y; 
       return *this;
   }
```

As for the postfix operator then it is defined correctly. As for me I would define it the following way

```
   const fix operator ++( int )
   {
       fix c( *this );
       ++x; ++y;

       return c;
   }
```

Or you could define it the following way

```
   const fix operator ++( int )
   {
       fix c( *this );

       ++*this; // or operator ++()

       return c;
   }
```

In main they can be called for example the following way

```
fix f1( 10, 10 );
fix f2 = f1++;
fix f3( 10, 10 );
fix f4 = ++f1;
fix f5( 10, 10 );
fix f6 = f5.operator++( 0 );
fix f7( 10, 10 );
fix f8 = f7.operator++();
```

Comment: Hmm why not reuse prefix operator++?

Comment: Agreed, with a comment: returning a `const` object is generally discouraged, it inhibits efficient moves.

Comment: How can i call these operators on main?